# on select multiple check boxes get all values using ReactJs with BootstrapUI

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox

Code below is to get selected values(Like a search refinement/search ). 
For Example, If I click on the Political Checkbox, I should get Political Value
If I click on the MovieCheckbox, I should get MovieValue as well as Political Value
If I uncheck It should display only selected checkbox value. Below is the code which I have written

```
class Refinments extends Component {
    render(){
    const { handleChange,handleClick } = this.props;
    return(
    <Form>
       {['checkbox'].map(type => (
            <div key={`Political`} className="mb-1">
              <Form.Check 
                type={type}
                custom 
                id={`Political}`}
                label={`Political`}
                value={`Political`}
                onChange={handleChange.bind(this, "Political")}
              />
            </div>
        ))}
        {['checkbox'].map(type => (
            <div key={`movies`} className="mb-1">
              <Form.Check 
            type={type} custom
            id={`movies}`}
            label={`Movies`}
            value={`Movies`}
             onChange={handleChange.bind(this, "Movies")}
              />
            </div>
        ))}
     </Form>
     )}

export default Refinments;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement and `['checkbox'].map` is pointless as there will be only one iteration and its value is going to be 'checkbox'.

Comment: @Dan Philip: From this URL, I have taken checkbox component
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-custom-checkboxes-and-radios
My requirement is refinements-filters

Comment: Can you share the code for this component class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to store the selected values in a state variable. `handleChange` method checks if the changed checkbox value is in the `valArr`, If it is present it removes the value from the array and replaces the state variable with the new array and if its not present it simply pushes the value into the array.

So `this.state.valArr` will always and only have the selected checkbox values.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    valArr: []
  }
}
handleChange = (val) => {
  let { valArr } = this.state;
  let index = valArr.indexOf(val);
  if (index != -1)
      valArr.splice(index, 1);
  else
      valArr.push(val);
  this.setState({ valArr });
}
render() {
  .
  .
  .
  <div key={`movies`} className="mb-1">
      <Form.Check 
        type={type} custom
        id={`movies}`}
        label={`Movies`}
        value={`Movies`}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
  </div>
}
```